# VS Extension dev: is there a list of built-in button icons?

Tags: forms, button, icons

I'm developing a Visual Studio Extension. Looking at some examples, I notice that there are built-in icons for buttons, such as the refresh button:

```
<Icon guid="guidOfficeIcon" id="msotcidRefresh"/>
```

My question is: is there a list of available IDs of this icon group "guidOfficeIcon"? Digging around the net I've found some others: msotcidClock, msotcidNoIcon, msotcidGears... But it would be nice to have a list of all of them.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I think I'm just going to search for some free .bmp icons online.

Comment: The Visual Studio Image Library is also useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I finally found it. The list of image ids can be found in the file msobtnid.h, which can be found here.

https://bitbucket.org/NickJosevski/jslint-for-vs2010-cli/src/b1e25667521e/vssdk_tools/Inc/office10/msobtnid.h

Answer (score 2):

I just spent a couple of hours looking for the same thing. The file can be found at Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common. In perfect 20/20 hindsight the answer was right in front of our eyes, the vcst file created by the vs package wizard specifies

```
<!--This is the file that defines the IDs for all the commands exposed by VisualStudio. -->
<Extern href="stdidcmd.h"/>
<!--This header contains the command ids for the menus provided by the shell. -->
<Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>
<!--Definition of some VSCT specific constants. In this sample we use it for the IDs inside the guidOfficeIcon group. -->
<Extern href="msobtnid.h"/>
```